# c# surface device and pressure input

Tags: c#, wpf, surface

i'm developing a simple application for a Windows Surface device (i have correctly installed the SDK v 2.0 and the runtime).
I'm developing the application on my laptop and then deploing it on the surface devia simpy via USB (i report this to give more information but i don't think the issue comes from here).

I've created a default project in WPF using the Surface template given via VisualStudio 2010 (even if i'm editing with VS 2012) and added some test

```
    public SurfaceWindow1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Add handlers for window availability events
        AddWindowAvailabilityHandlers();

        var Dev = Stylus.CurrentStylusDevice;
        Console.WriteLine(Dev != null ? Dev.ToString() : "null");
        Console.WriteLine(Dev != null ? Dev.TabletDevice.Type.ToString() : "null");

        StylusDown += new StylusDownEventHandler(SurfaceWindow1_StylusDown);
        MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(SurfaceWindow1_MouseDown);
        TouchDown += new EventHandler<TouchEventArgs>(SurfaceWindow1_TouchDown);

    }

    void SurfaceWindow1_StylusButtonDown(object sender, StylusButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stylus");
    }

    void SurfaceWindow1_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Touch");
    }

    void SurfaceWindow1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.StylusDevice == null ? "-" : e.StylusDevice.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Mouse");
    }

    void SurfaceWindow1_StylusDown(object sender, StylusDownEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stylus");
    }
```

Obviusly when running on my laptop the output at each mous click is the following

-
Mouse

So it's correcly using the right event (MouseDown).

The problem is the following: the output showed above is the same when i launch it on the Surface Device even if i press the screen with the Pen an not with the mouse pad integrated in the small keybord.  Furthermore if i press with the finger none of the tree event are raised (i expected that the Touch will be raised).

There's something i'm missing or doing it wrong?
Thanks in advice.

Additional info: as i said i'm developing in visual studio 2012 with .Net 4.5 and Windows 7. The Surface Device run a win 8.1 os

Comment: "Furthermore if i press with the finger none of the tree event are raised (i expected that the Touch will be raised)." I think touching with a finger raises the 'Tapped' event

Comment: I can't find the Tapped event, where i must look for it. The main focus is however the Stylus event, i need to gather the pressure of the pen in the screen (non the finger) but thanks for the advice.

Comment: I added more test, the pen is correclty connected and installed (some windows app recognize it's pressure) but i still cant find how to get pressure info from my c# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this.

Stylus event (don't know how) conflicted with the Surface SDK. Once i removed the SDK reference from the project all went smooth and the problem i solved.

I post this only for community information.